# Some Inequality from Fourier Series

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

Let $f \in L^2(\mathbb{T})$. 
 Let $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $$\|f-f_t\|_2 ^2 =\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}|c_n(f)(1-e^{-int})|^2.$$ Here  $$c_n(f)= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{[-\pi,\pi]}f(x)e^{-inx}dx.$$

Comment: What is $f_{t}$ supposed to represent?

Comment: Sorry that should be $f(x-t)$

Answer (score 0):

Try Parseval's theorem:

$$\|f-f_t\|_2^2= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |c_n(f)-c_n(f_t)|^2.$$

Now use the fact that $c_n(f_t)=e^{-int}c_n(f)$, by substitution in the integral and periodicity of $f$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: Yeah thank you very much i get it now. What about part (ii)?  I should i continue